# Bulk Operations in D365FO

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, bulkupdate

I have 500 records which I need to update in D365FO via API. Microsoft suggested that bulk operations are not applicable via ODATA in D365FO currently.

Can I get some help here How can I update all the records via API at one go.

Currently, I am looping all my records to be updated one at a time which is ok for 500 records but as my data grows it would be time-consuming.

Any suggestions about how I can bulk update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ExecuteMultiple** class to send the bulk requests to the server.

This [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamics-365-execute-multiple-request/) explain the usage of ExecuteMultiple and its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations,
you may use Data Management Framework (DMF) API.
It's about file Import / Export.
File format could be CSV, XML, or Excel.
JSON is available only through XSLT transformation. So, use CSV or XML.

[image: Import sequence]

[image: Export sequence]

Please find details here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-management-api
- https://github.com/microsoft/Recurring-Integrations-Scheduler/wiki#import-job
- https://azureintegrations.com/2019/10/15/d365fo-interacting-with-data-management-frame-work-using-rest-api-for-delta-changes-on-entity/
- https://filardi.cloud/2020/06/21/dynamics-365-finops-batch-import-automation-with-azure-functions-business-events-and-powerbi/